# Django/Celery - Filter each task result with periodic_task_name

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, django-celery-beat

I am quite new to Celery. Here is my code for configuring Celery Beat.

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # EMAILS
    'send-feedback-mail-every-2-weeks': {
        'task': 'stocks.tasks.send_ask_feedback',
        'schedule': crontab(day_of_week=6),
    },
    'get-terminal-data-frequently': {
        'task': 'stocks.tasks.get_terminal_data_func',
        'schedule': crontab(minute="*"),
    },
    # NEWS
    'get-newyorktimes-api': {
        'task': 'stocks.tasks.get_news_nyt',
        'schedule': crontab(minute="*"),
    },
}
```

I am wondering how to query the associated tasks for the periodic task `get-newyorktimes-api` in my view to pass the result of each into the context. I tried:

```
context['celery'] = TaskResult.objects.filter(periodic_task_name='get-newyorktimes-api')
```

It returned an empty queryset even though I've run the task successfully multiple times. Where is my fault in this Task filter?